# How to invoke RequireJS modules from old non-AMD Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am now trying to modulize my javascript code using RequireJS. I have 2 JS files (let's say A and B). A is a big file that has main code for my html page. B is a small utility library which is designed to be used by A and any other code in the future.

My plan is to firstly modulize B since B is small. After this I can write all my new code using RequireJS in the future and use B. On the other hand I will gradually modulize A. My concern now is that after I modulize B, is there a way that file A can continue use code in B so that my app can work correctly?

I cannot find out anything about this. Any suggestions, articles or sample code are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find out the answer myself. Actually it's very straight forward. just use RequireJS in your old code. For instance if I need to use JQuery in my old non-modulized code via RequireJS, I just need to:

first configure JQuery in the main.js

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl : '../js',
  paths : {
    'jquery' : 'jquery/jquery-1.10.2'
  },
  }
});
```

and add the main.js in the html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/require.js" data-main="../js/main.js"></script>
```

Then in the old code, use the function requirejs to ask the module (JQuery in this case) and invoke the module's functions.

```
  requirejs([ 'jquery' ],function(jquery)
  {
    jquery('#id').on('click',function(event){...});
  });
```

With this way, one can always gradually modulize code from a big, old and non-modulized JavaScript file step by step.